# How to check if value exists in struct or not?

Tags: arrays, c, validation, struct

I want to ask you guys, here my code cannot check is my value is exist or not in struct, I've input the value, but none of them enter the if else condition, can anyone help me?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main(){
    int a,i;
    struct data {
        char nim[10];
    };
    
    struct data batas[100];
        
    printf("TEST1 : "); scanf("%[^\n]s", batas[0].nim);
    printf("TEST2 : "); scanf(" %[^\n]s", batas[1].nim);
    printf("TEST3 : "); scanf(" %[^\n]s", batas[3].nim);
        
    printf("TEST : "); scanf(" %[^\n]s", batas[a].nim);
    for(i=0; i<a; i++){
        if (batas[a].nim == batas[i].nim) {
            printf("Value exist");
        } else {
            printf("Value doesn't exist");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a is not set anywhere

Comment: Your variable `a` is not initialized. The default *could* be set to 0 so the `for` loop never executes.

Comment: "I've input the value," --> What values were used?

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s"` --> `scanf(" %9[^\n]"` to avoid buffer overflow.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i use input string with space value

Comment: @RudyTriSaputra Best to post exact input than only describe input.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i input "rudy tri saputra" as value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not compare array of `char`s with the equal operator, instead:

```
if (strcmp(batas[a].nim, batas[i].nim) == 0)
```

or

```
if (!strcmp(batas[a].nim, batas[i].nim))
```

you need to `#include <string.h>`

Also, note that you are using `a` uninitialized.

Comment: Shouldn't `strcmp(batas[a].nim == batas[i].nim)` be `strcmp(batas[a].nim, batas[i].nim)`?

Comment: @DavidRanieri Sorry, from this code you give, i've initialize a with a=0, but it still not entered to the "value exist"

Answer (score 0):

from what you give, it still can't enter the "Value exist" value. Here are my full line of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct data {
    char nim[10];
};

struct data batas[100];
int a=0, b, c, d;
int i, j;
char x[20];

void inputdata()
{
  printf("\nInput Data\n");
  printf("=======================\n");
  printf("NIM : "); scanf("%s", batas[a].nim);
  for(i=0; i<a; i++){
    if (!strcmp(batas[a].nim, batas[i].nim)) {
      strcpy(x, "FLAG");
    } else {
      strcpy(x, "FLAGX");
    }
  }
  printf("%s", x);
  a++;
}

void showdata()
{
  j=0;
  for(i=0; i<a; i++){
    j = j + 1;
    printf("\nData-%i", j);
    printf("\nNIM : %s", batas[i].nim);
  }
}

int main() {
  int menu;
  do {
    printf("\nChoose input = "); scanf("%d", &menu);
    switch(menu)
    {
      case 1 : inputdata(); break;
      case 2 : showdata(); break;
    }
  }while (menu != 3);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you set `a` to 0 the loop is never executed because the condition `a >= 0` is false, do you mean `int a = 100;`?

Comment: @DavidRanieri i've tried change a to 100, but in the result by checking my `showdata()` it got the result full of `a` array. I just realized that from my `for(i=0; i<a; i++){` condition, it can't get the exact value, it always get and "FLAGX" result (always get end of array result)

Comment: Have you checked the link provided in a comment in my answer?

Comment: @DavidRanieri Yes, i've check it, thank you David, initially I wanted to take the condition if `batas[a].nim == batas[i].nim`, but after I tried to take the value `x`, it turns out that it always takes the lastest result, not the result I have set. like `x = FLAG`

Comment: uff, I no longer follow you, if the requirements have changed I suggest to ask a new question

Comment: @DavidRanieri She [did](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65858579/3150802).