# How to stop and get exact result from For loop in C language

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, struct

How to get an exit from `for` loop because my code always gets the latest result from the `for` loop? What's wrong with my `for` loop condition? This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main(){
    int i, n = 3, a;
    char x[20];
    struct data {
        char nim[10];
    };
 
    struct data batas[100];
 
    printf("TEST1 : "); scanf("%[^\n]s", batas[0].nim);
    printf("TEST2 : "); scanf(" %[^\n]s", batas[1].nim);
    printf("TEST3 : "); scanf(" %[^\n]s", batas[2].nim);
 
    char str[10];
    printf("TEST : "); scanf(" %[^\n]s", str);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        if (strcmp(str, batas[i].nim) == 0) {
            puts("Value exist");
            strcpy(x, "FLAG");
        } else {
            puts("Value doesn't exist");
            strcpy(x, "FLAGXX");
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, from the result of `x` always gets the `FLAGXX` result. I want to get the `FLAG` result here.

Comment: `"%[^\n]s"` -> `"%[^\n]"`

Comment: When you find the value, set the flag and **exit the loop**, otherwise the next run through the loop will check an inexistent value.

Comment: That loop is structured wrong in the first place. The default value (i.e. no match) should be setup *before* the loop, and the loop should `break;` after the inner body (the `if`) tests true and therefore sets `FLAG`.

Comment: Initialize with "FLAGXX" prior to the loop and just don't overwrite with "FLAGXX" inside the loop. (assuming you do want the `Value exist`/`Value doesn't exist` output for every element)

Comment: The best way to get the exact result is to not overwrite it with an inexact result.

Comment: If the string you enter for `str` matches the last of your three values, you should get the result you want.  But because you overwrite `x` on each iteration, you get `FLAGXX` otherwise.  Break when you find the value.

Comment: @Jonathan I don't appreciate your edit. The quality of the question's original language corresponded to the quality of the question and hence was an aid to understanding it.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica — you can go 'fix' it if you don't like it.

Comment: `"%[^\n]s"` -> `"%9[^\n]"`  For `%s` and `%[`, you must *always* use a maximum width.

Comment: Oh. Did you mean "get **exit** result" in your title??

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Thank you, it sovled now, i just need `break` for stop my code from the loop

Comment: You are welcome. Let me give you a piece of advice, or two. (1) if your program behaves funny, debug it. If you are on Windows, simply use the free [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) "Community Edition". Coding and debugging with it  It is a smooth experience.*Visual Studio Code* runs even on Linux. Alternatively, you can always (and should have here) use "printf debugging". That is, you insert printf statement at strategic places in your program to see where the control flow goes and what values variables have. That would have shown your error quickly.

Comment: (2) If you post here, try to use sober, clear, correct and unambiguous English. "Hey guys" indicates that you are not serious (and my remark earlier to Jonathan meant that it indicated to me that you didn't put serious effort into your programming, or into finding the error yourself). The language is the first impression you make here. (3) What you did better than many is that you presented to us a complete example. We could look at it and see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to get the exact result is to not overwrite it with an inexact result. You want x to contain "FLAG" if one of the strings was matched; but unless it was the last loop iteration, `x` will be overwritten later when a non-match is encountered.

One typical algorithm would be to `break` the for loop when a match is found. (An explanation of `break` and the oppositionally related `continue`can be found [here](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-break-continue-statement), which happens to be the first google hit.)

I would also recommend to simply use a boolean flag which is false when the loop is entered and set to true when a match is found; there is no reason to copy strings around (and the same string!) during every iteration.

Comment: Thank you peter, it solved now, it just need `break` only to stop from the loop